# Want to get route path between two location using address of the place in Google Map V2( without using Latitude and Longitude)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Please help, I am able to get route path between two location using its latitude and longitude in Google Map V2, but i want to get the route path by using the address of the place. Is it possible? If possible please guide me to do it.

Comment: Add some more information, like how do you get the coordinates.

Comment: I am new for the google map sdk. i followed the way give in the linkhttp://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html , where the latitude and longitude is passed to url for getting the other point to draw the route. Likewise i want to draw the route by passing the address of the two location.

Comment: The tutorial is using the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en) and it takes String for the origin and the destination too, not only latitude and longitude values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't draw a route path without having two LatLng point, but you can get those point from an address using the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object.

Next, you would just paint a Polyline on the map using the 2 LatLng point you have found using the Geocoder, to do that you can follow this guide I wrote on this topic:

[Draw Driving Direction on Map:](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
 List<Address> address;

try {
   address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
     if (address == null) {
       return null;
}
Address location = address.get(0);
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();

p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                  (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

 return p1;
}
```

get latitude and longitude and use those for navigation